# Installed Gitolite using root (dumb), locked myself out of ssh

Tags: git, ssh, telnet, gitolite, nas

I tried following this guide to set up my Synology DS212J NAS:
http://www.bluevariant.com/2012/05/comprehensive-guide-git-gitolite-synology-diskstation/

I tried using the user "git" to install originally, but ran into a lot of permissions/access denied errors, so I tried it in root.  This seemed successful.

However, now I am no longer able to login to my server via ssh (as Gitolite blocks ssh).

Is there a way to undo this?

I also have Telnet enabled, and I seem to be able to login using:

```
telnet iptonas
```

And I get:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1-hpn13v11
```

But Telnet is completely alien to me.  Does anyone have any suggestions that might point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is telnet giving you prompts for login and password?

Comment: @brepro No, it's not.  It just connects me right away.

Comment: So you're getting a prompt of some sort?  Telnet logs you into a shell, by default, just like ssh does (by default), it's just not secure (everything is sent plaintext, passwords and all, no option to use RSA keys for authentication, etc).

Answer (score 2):

As [brepro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/809452/brepro) comments, if the telnet access gives you a prompt, you will get a bidirectional interactive text-oriented communications facility, meaning you can do again your Gitolite installation.

You will need to remove the forced command generated for the root account first, as described in your [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/430903/cannot-login-to-ssh-after-installing-gitolite-pty-allocation-request-failed-on).
Then, you can follow again the [installation procedure](http://www.bluevariant.com/2012/05/comprehensive-guide-git-gitolite-synology-diskstation/), but making sure to use a different account than root when typing:

```
/volume1/homes/git/gitolite/install -ln
```

(which defaults to $HOME/bin for a regular user)

Using `root` would modify again the `authorized_keys` file of the `root` account, with a forced command making (again) any interactive shell ssh connection impossible.